# How do I avoid dir(my module) listing every package imported by my module in python?

Tags: python, python-import

Say I've written a python module called `my_module`:

```py
# my_module.py

import numpy as np

def my_function():
    print("Hello, module!")
```

Then I import `my_module` and inspect it using the built-in function `dir()`:

```py
>>> import my_module
>>> dir(my_module)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'my_function', 'np']
```

`np` shows up in the list of names defined by `my_module`. This is annoying because I often want to use `dir()` to figure out what functions / classes, etc., are available via `my_module`. But in the result above, it's not clear to me how to tell whether `np` is native to `my_module` or if it's just some package that `my_module` imported, which (*in my opinion*) obfuscates the functionality of `my_module`.

So my question is, how do I structure `my_module` so that only the functions / classes / etc. it defines show up in `dir(my_module)`? Or equivalently, so that `dir(my_module)` doesn't print out every module imported in `my_module.py`?

I figure:

1. This is possible, because `dir(other popular packages)` often don't appear to list their every import:

   ```py
   >>> import scipy
   >>> print([x for x in dir(scipy) if "np" in x])
   ['nanpercentile', 'nanprod', 'nper', 'npv', 'unpackbits']

   >>> print([x for x in dir(scipy) if "numpy" in x])
   ['__numpy_version__', 'show_numpy_config']
   ```
2. Or maybe they do, and that fact has just escaped me,
3. Or I might be using `dir()` in a way that wasn't intended, and nobody cares if a bunch of imports appear in `dir(my_module)`, and this is a  waste of time.

Comment: Try it on those other packages without the list comprehension.

Comment: You can `print(scipy.__file__)` to see it what it does. Scipy doesn't do `import numpy as np` so we wouldn't expect "np" to be in its `dir`. It does `import numpy as _num` but then does `del _num` at the end. Since this is scipy's `__init__.py` module I assume that code needed numpy is in submodules. In fact `dir(scipy)` has all the junk your module has.

Answer (score 5):

From the [`dir` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir):

> If the object is a module object, the list contains the names of the module’s attributes.

Imported modules are attributes, and so appear in the list. But this can be overridden

> If the object has a method named **dir**(), this method will be called
> and must return the list of attributes.

So you could get the `dir` you want by writing a function that returns what you want.

```
# my_module.py

import numpy as np

def my_function():
    print("Hello, module!")

def __dir__():
    return ["my_function"]
```

But this is error prone... you have to keep up the list. I think a better way is to use python's doc strings and help instead. This is what its for. You control how chatty your documentation should be.

```
"""My module

Filled with my things.
"""

import numpy as np

def my_function():
    """Print the message"""
    print("Hello, module!")
```

example

```
>>> import my_module
>>> help(my_module)

Help on module my_module:

NAME
    my_module - My module

DESCRIPTION
    Filled with my things.

FUNCTIONS
    my_function()
        Print the message

FILE
    /home/td/tmp/a/my_module.py
```

Comment: It looks like OP wants a list of the functions and classes, not the doc/help output.

Comment: @j1mbl3s - I've updated with a way to override `dir` to more directly answer the question but I still think that doc strings are the right way to solve the problem.